# React: Sorting and filter product by price and size using react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to filter product by size and also sort it by size but when I implement it in redux I get the error that map its not a function in product component here is my action Creator page. This is where I fetch the product from server

```
export const fetchProduct = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(productLoading(true));

  return fetch(baseUrl + "products")
    .then(
      (response) => {
        console.log('response',response)
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error(
            "Error " + response.status + ": " + response.statusText
          );
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((products) => dispatch(addProduct(products)))
    .catch((error) => dispatch(productFailed(error.message)));
};

export const productLoading = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.PRODUCT_LOADINGS,
});

export const productFailed = (errmess) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.PRODUCT_FAILURES,
  payload: errmess,
});

export const addProduct = (products) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCTS,
  payload: products,
});

    
export const filterProducts = (product, size) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
    payload: {
      size: size,
      products:
        size === ""
          ? product
          : product.filter((x) => x.availableSizes.indexOf(size) >= 0),
    },
  });
};
```

Here is where I short  and filter the product

```
export const sortProducts = (sort, filteredProduct) => (dispatch) => {
  

      const sortedProduct = filteredProduct.slice();
      if (sort === "latest") {
        
        sortedProduct.sort((a, b) => (a._id > b._id ? 1 : -1));
      } else {
        
        sortedProduct.sort((a, b) =>
          sort === "lowest"
            ? a.price > b.price
              ? 1
              : -1
            : a.price > b.price
            ? -1
            : 1
        );
      }
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.SORT_PRODUCT_BY_PRICE,
        payload: { sort: sort, products: sortedProduct },
      });
    };
```

This is my productReducer.js page

```
import * as ActionTypes from "./ActionsType";

export const productsReducer = (
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    errMess: null,
    products: [],
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
      return {
        ...state,
        size: action.payload.size,
        filteredItems: action.payload.products,
      };
    case ActionTypes.SORT_PRODUCT_BY_PRICE:
      return {
        
        ...state,
        sort: action.payload.sort,
        filteredItems: action.payload.products,
      };
    case ActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCTS:
      console.log(" products: action.payload, filteredItems:action.payload", {
        products: action.payload,
        filteredItems: action.payload,
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errMess: null,
        products: action.payload,
        filteredItems: action.payload,
      };

    case ActionTypes.PRODUCT_LOADINGS:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, products: [] };

    case ActionTypes.PRODUCT_FAILURES:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errMess: action.payload,
        products: [],
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my main component where I passed the product as props to product component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Footer from "./FooterComponent";
import { Header } from "./HeaderComponent";
import Product from "./ProductsComponent";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Sidebar } from "./Sidebars";
import {
  addProductToCart,
  addToCart,
  decrementCartQuantity,
  fetchProduct,
  filterProducts,
  incrementCartQuantity,
  loginUser,
  removeFromCart,
  SignUpReq,
  sortProducts,
} from "../redux/ActionCreators";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ProductDetailsComponent from "./ProductDetailsComponent";
import SignupForm from "./signup";
import AboutUs from "./AboutUs";
import { actions } from "react-redux-form";
import Signup from "./Signup copy 2";
import CartItemsComponent from "./CartItemsComponent";
import Filter from "./Filter";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: state.product.filteredItems,
    product: state.product.products,
    size: state.product.size,
    sort: state.product.sort,
    filteredProducts: state.product.filteredItems,
  };
};

  

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      fetchProduct: () => dispatch(fetchProduct()),
      
      filterProducts: () => dispatch(filterProducts()),
      sortProducts: () => dispatch(sortProducts()),
      

  },
  
});

class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProduct();
  }
  render() {
    const GetItem = ({ match, params }) => {
      return (
        <ProductDetailsComponent
          product={
            this.props.products.filter(
              (product) => product._id === match.params.productId
            )[0]
          }
          isLoading={this.props.products.isLoading}
          errMess={this.props.products.errMess}
          addToCart={this.props.addToCart}
        />
      );
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          loginUser={this.props.loginUser}
          cartItems={this.props.cartItems}
        />
        <Filter
          filterProducts={this.props.filterProducts}
          sortProducts={this.props.sortProducts}
          product={this.props.products}
          filteredProducts={this.props.filteredProducts}
        />

        <Switch>
          
         
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => (
              <Product
                product={this.props.products}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/:productId" component={GetItem} />
          <Route exact path="/contactus" />
          <Redirect to="/default" />
        </Switch>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

This is my ProductsComponent.js page

```
import React from "react";
import { Loading } from "./LoadingComponent";
import { GridWrapper } from "./StyleComponent";
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardTitle,
  Button,
  Breadcrumb,
  BreadcrumbItem,
} from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { baseUrl } from "./shared/baseUrl";
import formatCurrency from "./shared/util";

function RenderProductItem({ product, addToCart }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card">
        <Link to={`/${product._id}`}>
          <div className="img-container p-5">
            <img
              src={baseUrl + product.image}
              alt={product.title}
              className="card-img-top"
            />
          </div>
        </Link>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <p className="align-self-center mb-0">{product.title}</p>
          <h5 className="text-blue  align-self-center font-italic mb-0">
            <span className="mr-1">{formatCurrency(product.price)}</span>
          </h5>
        </div>

       

        <div className="card-footer ">
          <button
            className="buttonContainer col-12"
            onClick={() => {
              addToCart(product);
            }}
          >
            add-to-cart
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


    function Product(props) {
      console.log( "props", props)
      const products = props.product.map((product) => {
        return (
          <div key={product._id} className="col-12 mx-auto col-md-5  my-3">
            <RenderProductItem product={product} addToCart={props.addToCart} />
          </div>
        );
      });
      if (props.product.isLoading) {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <Loading />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

     else if (props.product.errMess) {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <h4>{props.product.errMess}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else
        return (
          <>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <Breadcrumb>
                  <BreadcrumbItem>
                    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                  </BreadcrumbItem>
                  <BreadcrumbItem active>Products</BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
                <div className="col-12">
                  <h3>Products</h3>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">{products}</div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
    }

export default Product;
```

This is my filter.js page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Filter extends Component {
    render() {
      return !this.props.filteredProducts ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="filter">
          <div className="filter-result">
            {this.props.filteredProducts.length} Products
          </div>
          <div className="filter-sort">
            Order{" "}
            <select
              value={this.props.sort}
              onChange={(e) =>
                this.props.sortProducts(
                  this.props.filteredProducts,
                  e.target.value
                )
              }
            >
              <option value="latest">Latest</option>
              <option value="lowest">Lowest</option>
              <option value="highest">Highest</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="filter-size">
            Filter{" "}
            <select 
              value={this.props.size}
              onChange={(e) =>
                this.props.filterProducts(this.props.product, e.target.value)
              }
            >
              <option value="">ALL</option>
              <option value="XS">XS</option>
              <option value="S">S</option>
              <option value="M">M</option>
              <option value="L">L</option>
              <option value="XL">XL</option>
              <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Filter
```

Comment: I would store the sort and filter info in the state and use selectors to sort and filter it.

Comment: Please i dont kno how to use selectors can you please help me on how to achieve it with that code